# Lower bound on $P(X \geq \theta E [X] )$

Tags: probability, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable and $\theta \in [0,1]$. Show that:

$$\mathbb P\left(X \geq \theta \, \mathbb E X\right ) \geq (1-\theta)^2\frac{\mathbb E [X]^2}{\mathbb E[ X^2] - \theta(2-\theta)\mathbb E[X]^2}$$

**What I've tried**

This is very similar to the Paley-Zygmund inequality (in which case the denominator is missing the second term). I don't think the proof for PZ is adaptable here (unless we can apply something stronger than Cauchy-Schwarz):

$$\mathbb E X = \mathbb E X \mathbb 1(X < \theta \mathbb E X) + \mathbb E X \mathbb 1(X\geq \theta \mathbb E X) \leq \theta \mathbb E X + \sqrt {\mathbb E X \mathbb P(X \geq\theta \, \mathbb EX)}$$

Where the inequality is from cauchy-schwarz. Simplifying gives the PZ inequality. If I can get a tighter bound on the second term then I should be able to show the inequality of interest.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the denominator in the inequality is exactly $\mathbb{E}[(X - \theta \mathbb{E}[X])^2]$, so you can apply Cauchy-Schwarz to (an upper bound of) $\mathbb{E}[X - \theta \mathbb{E}[X]]$.

Comment: Wouldnt I want a lower bound on the denominator?

Comment: It looks like if I can lower bound $E(X-\theta E X)1(X\geq \theta E X)$ by the numerator then using your hint I am done (since I can upper bound this expression using CS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your denominator is exactly $\mathbb{E}[(X - \theta \mathbb{E}[X])^2]$. So we have the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(1 - \theta) \mathbb{E}[X] &= \mathbb{E}[X - \theta E[X]] \leq \mathbb{E}\big[(X - \theta \mathbb{E}[X]) 1\{X - \theta \mathbb{E}[X] \geq 0\}\big] \\
&\overset{\text{(C.S.)}}{\leq} \sqrt{\mathbb{P}(X \geq \theta \mathbb{E}[X])} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(X - \theta \mathbb{E}[X])^2]}
\end{aligned}
$$

Rearranging will give you the result.